# flash based facebook application with dynamic height, i can't see the all height of the application

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to create a facebook application that is flash (actually flex 4.1) based.

I load the flash application using the following command:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="XpoDemo" name="XpoDemo" data="file.swf"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="flashvars" value=""></object>
```

The problem is that in the facebook page I cannot see the full height of my application, it's missing like 150px.

any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [FB.Canvas.setSize](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize) or [FB.Canvas.setAutoResize](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoResize) (if the height changes during use)